# How to connect Hive in iReport?

Tags: hadoop, jasper-reports, ireport, hive

I am using `Hadoop-0.20.0` and `Hive-0.8.0`. Now i have data into Hive table and i want generate reports from that. For that I am using `iReport-4.5.0`. For that I also download `HivePlugin-0.5.nbm` in `iReport`.

Now I am going to connect Hive connection in `iReport`.

*Create New Data source --> New --> Hive Connection*

***Jdbc Drive***: **org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver**

***Jdbc URl***: **jdbc:hive//localhost:10000/default**

***Server Address***: **localhost**

***Database***: **default**

***user name***: **root**

***password***: **somepassword**

Then click on Test connection button.

I am getting error like:

```
Exception

Message:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal Hadoop Version: Unknown (expected A.B.* format)

Level:

SEVERE

Stack Trace:

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal Hadoop Version: Unknown (expected A.B.* format)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:226)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:72)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:110)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.getConnection(JDBCConnection.java:140)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.hadoop.hive.connection.HiveConnection.getConnection(HiveConnection.java:48)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.test(JDBCConnection.java:447)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog.jButtonTestActionPerformed(ConnectionDialog.java:335)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog.access$300(ConnectionDialog.java:43)
```

Can any one help me in this? Where i am wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 2):

"I also download HivePlugin-0.5.nbm in iReport."
This isn't clear. iReport 4.5 has the Hadoop Hive connector pre-installed. Why did you download the connector separately? Did you install this plugin?

> Create New Data source --> New --> Hive Connection
>   Jdbc Drive: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
>
> ...

This isn't possible with the current Hadoop Hive connector. When you create a new "Hadoop Hive Connection" you are given only one parameter to fill out: the url.
[image]

I'm guessing that you created a JDBC connection when you meant to create a Hadoop Hive connection. This is a logical thing to do. Hive is accessed via JDBC. But the Hive JDBC driver is still pretty new. It has a number of shortcomings. That's why the Hive connector was added to iReport. It is based on the Hive JDBC driver, but it includes a wrapper around it to avoid some problems.

Or maybe you installed an old Hive connector over the top of the one that's already included with iReport 4.5. At some point in the past the Hive connector let you fill in extra information like the JDBC Driver.

Start with a fresh iReport installation, and make sure you use the Hadoop Hive Connection. That should clear it up.

Comment: we started with the default connector that comes with i-Report as it was not working properly, we had to try install the connector separately and check. Even that was not working!

Thanks for your suggestion, we will try re-install the i-Report and check if it works!

Comment: I understand your logic. But the posted .nbm files on jasperforge.org were all older. The one in iReport is latest and best. If it fails... then please post the problems.

Comment: Ahh... I see that you're using Hive-0.8.0. That's probably the problem. The Hive connector in iReport includes only 0.7, and Hive is not friendly about being backwards compatible with older drivers. Solution: grab the source and build yourself with updated Hive jars, or wait for a new release to be posted soon on jasperforge.org.

Answer (score 1):

The error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal Hadoop Version: Unknown (expected A.B.* format)" happens because the VersionInfo class in hadoop-common.jar attempts to locate the version info using the current thread's class loader.

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.6.0/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/VersionInfo.java#L41-L58

The code in question looks like this...

```
package org.apache.hadoop.util;
...
public class VersionInfo {
...
  protected VersionInfo(String component) {
    info = new Properties();
    String versionInfoFile = component + "-version-info.properties";
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(versionInfoFile);
      if (is == null) {
        throw new IOException("Resource not found");
      }
      info.load(is);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      LogFactory.getLog(getClass()).warn("Could not read '" +
          versionInfoFile + "', " + ex.toString(), ex);
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeStream(is);
    }
  }
```

If your tool attempts to connect to the datasource in a separate thread, it will generate this error.

The easiest way to work around the issue is to put the hadoop-common.jar library in $JAVA_HOME/lib/ext or use the command line setting -Djava.endorsed.dirs to point to the hadoop-common.jar library. Then the thread's class loader will always be able to find this information.